# How do I get IIS to tell me what errors are on the server?

Tags: asp.net

[image]

what i need is simply to view the error, change the setting so they are viewable remotely.

this is my Web.Config file

[image]

help????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Display of  Errors at in a  Web Site: Enable the Errors to be  Displayed then Custom Local or Remote.

So if "Send Errors To Browser" is not working set also this:

**Error Pages -> 500 -> Edit Feature Settings -> "Detailed Erros"**

Or try

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: ok so i changed my config file to this:
http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/6962/d403e5f5180040bc8d20f31.png
and now the message is this:
http://i.imgur.com/HKgUC.png

Answer (score 0):

You must set the customErrors mode to "Off", as the message in the first screenshot says. Removing the default redirect will probably help.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using [Elmah (Error Logging Modules and Handlers)](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for better remote log viewing mechanism, it is very easy to implement either through NuGet or follow instructions [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/07/24/securely-implement-elmah-for-plug-and-play-error-logging.aspx). I am using Elmah for a long time and suggest this.